# Google Apps Script: Form submission failed when call google.script.run

Tags: google-apps-script

From June 24th, 2015 I have a problem in GAS. Before, everything worked but not anymore.

The code is visible here [scriptLink](https://script.google.com/d/1kWirOVGph2nqdU9WMFtLU9iNZ2dCGC5hADqrSy2ytbkosFNhPbrh9q8D/edit?usp=sharing) 
and executable here [executeLink](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwMPU552h2nrK26OFCnYoZHAuW9D57uxl0hdaryIkTBKdct466E/exec)

I work with HTMLService. I have the get method:

```
function doGet(request) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html');
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

The Form.html contains:

```
<input type="button" value="1 STEP - Error Call" onclick="console.log('chiamo il server con input testo...'); google.script.run.withFailureHandler(setBlankFullName).withSuccessHandler(setFullName).getTest('test')" />
<input type="button" value="1 STEP - Correct Call" onclick="console.log('chiamo il server con input form...'); google.script.run.withFailureHandler(setBlankFullName).withSuccessHandler(setFullName).getTest(document.getElementById('myForm'))" />
<br/>
<input type="button" value="2 STEP - SUBMIT"  
  onclick="google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)          
      .processForm(document.getElementById('myForm'));" />
```

If I click the button "1 STEP - Error Call" and then "2 STEP - SUBMIT" I get this error: **Form submission failed.**
Why?

And it's very strange that if I click the button "1 STEP - Correct Call" and then "2 STEP - SUBMIT" the form works fine!
The difference is in type of input parameter. 
To operate all the calls of my form I had to pass in the input parameters always the same data type: in this case: the form. If you change all the input parameters in strings, the form works properly, if there is at least one of a different type, the form returns **Form submission failed.**.

I don't understand why there is this error, whereas before they were supported different data types.

Comment: There is an issue related to this problem. you can post the issue you are getting and also check if a solution is provided: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5189